# Can't read database name web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-connections

Trying to read the database name but it's not working in the site. Using an asp.net web project with a solution file. I put this in the web.config. This will change depending on development database or production database PRODDB via the web configuration transform files and scripts.

```
    <appSettings>
        <add key="databaseName" value="DEVELDB"/>
        <add key="operatingEnvironment" value="dev"/>
    </appSettings>
```

***Within the Global.asax.cs file:***

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
           
            var operatingEnvironment = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["operatingEnvironment"].ToString();

            if (operatingEnvironment == "dev")
            {
                Application["DBE"] = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

***Within the login.cs class file:***

```
 internal static DatabaseConnection GetDatabaseConnection()
            {

                return

                    new DatabaseConnection(
                        new ConnectionProperties
                        {
                            User = Shared.User,
                            Application = Shared.Application,
                            DatabaseName = (string)HttpContext.Current.Application["DBE"]
                        });
            }
```

***and within the Web.Development.config file there is:***

```
    <appSettings>
        <add key="databaseName" value="DEVELDB" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
        <add key="operatingEnvironment" value="dev" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </appSettings>
```

However, whenever I debug after login, it goes to the code below which is good (the same as coded above) but says Database name was not specified? I have it specified as DEVELDB and using "DBE" to reference it. However, it's not like it debugs to another area and to there, just straight to there and kills it?

```
...
  {
                            User = Shared.User,
                            Application = Shared.Application,
                            DatabaseName = (string)HttpContext.Current.Application["DBE"]
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Connections to databases go inside the "connectionstrings" tags in you "webconfig" file. If you need SqlServer it is shown below

```
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TwoWayConn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TwoWayData.accdb"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="TWOWAYDATASQL" connectionString="Data Source=TBIRD\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=TWOWAYDATASQL.MDF;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
....

    </configuration>
```

Am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi @GailV,

Actually, we do things differently here for the DB connection and this even more of a different way within a web project. However, I decided to do it the original way to reference the database in the Global.asax file and add the connection data in a class. Thank you!